# To access share point 2007 list with web services

Tags: php, web-services, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I want to access share point 2007 list with the help of a web-service API. My preferable language is PHP. How can i go about doing it. How can i start it.  Any help is appreciated. Somebody who can give some insights on this as i am new to share point.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried anything yet?

This forum is here to help people who have started but are stuck.

This may be a good starting point for you

http://www.robertkuzma.com/2011/07/manipulating-sharepoint-list-items-with-php/

As a recommendation i would always search google for a bit to see if you can find what you are looking for there seems to be plenty of examples which should get you to a point where you can come back here and say i am doing this but not sure why it isn't working.